# How to pitch bend in Timbre.js

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm using Timbre.js (newest version 14.10.12 http://mohayonao.github.io/timbre.js/) and I'm trying to figure out how to bend a pitch. I'm currently using PluckGen to play the tone.

My code looks basically like this so far:

```
var env = T("perc", {a:100, r:500});
var pluck = T("PluckGen", {env:env, mul:0.5}).play();

// Play an E
pluck.noteOn(64, 200);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was answered on twitter by the author of Timbre.js:

https://twitter.com/iamjwc/status/557606407084978176?lang=en

"Pluckgen cannot bend a pitch. I have no idea, too. Thanks!"

There you have it, folks. Can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `jukebox.js` using a modulator.

http://danielstern.github.io/jukeboxjs/#/demo